# Git push getting failed. error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60

Tags: git, curl, bitbucket, git-push

When I am trying to push my code to `bitbucket`, I am getting this error in terminal.

```
* LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 2
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

**The solutions which I already tried**

1. Increasing git buffer size : `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`
2. Deleted .git and re-initiated setup
3. Restarted network. (Not a network issue though)
4. Restarted system.
5. Checked code base for files which are greater than 100MB to reset from commit. None of the files exceeds the limit.
6. Added `export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1`, `export GIT_TRACE=1`, `export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` to check the verbose logs, None were logged except the above error.

Any help that solves the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you on? With which version of Git? Did you try for testing without the firewall? AV? (AntiVirus)? See for instance https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1636#issuecomment-331702493 or https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/issues/1413#issuecomment-383255666

Comment: @VonC I am on MBP, git `2.13.6`, I have switched firewall off as well and tested. Forgot to mention in the question. I was trying to push xcode project with no luck

Comment: @VonC Any help?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your previous comment. Would the issue persist with Git 2.18? It is related to carthage? (https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1636#issuecomment-267964771) What does `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` return?

Comment: @VonC Other projects which are not xcode project, I am able to push it to bitbucket. Only problem with xcode projects..

Comment: OK. No clues, except for what is described in https://www.talentica.com/blogs/build-custom-android-rom-using-android-open-source-projectaosp/

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you have a problem in your network infrastructure!

It might be related to your tools or periodic poor network connection or some middle-wares on network those affect on packets!

There is some other rare situations if you won't get answer from rest of this answer, these rare situations need to be considered and analyzed.

Some following actions might help you to pass this situations:

1. Increase git buffer by `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`
2. Disable SSL validation on git! through: `git config http.sslVerify false`
   => (Don't forget IF YOU DIDN'T GET ANSWER from this, "ROLL IT BACK!")
3. Run(Establish) a High-Quality VPN and do git actions through that!

If you find one of these as your solution, please mention that as comment to be useful for others, and If you don't find them useful, describe more about your network quality or tools, to let us analyze and help better.

Comment: Increase the git buffer do the trick in my case! Thanks.

Comment: Git buffer did it for me as well

Answer (score 6):

I was able to push from one repo and not the other, weirdly. None of the solutions I found online worked for me, but **restarting my VPN worked for me.** Maybe this will help someone.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 1):

**My solution might seem stupid**, but it worked for me because of Mac sleeping issue.
I had been building from git code repo and had got stuck with similar error, because of **nw disruption due to Mac going to Sleep state**.

Just **used amphetamine and ran the build** and it worked a charm.

This might not be the solution for you, but this helped for me. Cheers

Comment: yes, you are the hero

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try with a stronger network connection because it seems your repo has a large file size.

Answer (score 0):

**Connect with a different and appropriate VPN**. It resolves the issue. May be the current VPN has limit on size of the repository.

Also, the full error message below suggests error with the remote connection.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
fatal: **the remote end hung up unexpectedly**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I encountered the issue when using git pull for a git repository. I fixed the issue by making use of a good VPN.