# How do I diagnose my home network for git clone failures?

Tags: git, curl, networking, openssl

I frequently get an error when cloning a large repository from GitHub (specifically, Chromium, but it doesn't matter) on my local network, after downloading about ~10 GB:

```
git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g clone --no-checkout --progress https://github.com/chromium/chromium

Cloning into '<path to dir>'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 15975048, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (6505/6505), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3237/3237), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I read up on several StackOverflow questions with the same issue[[0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120225/git-push-getting-failed-error-rpc-failed-curl-56-libressl-ssl-read-ssl-error)][[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232906/git-clone-error-rpc-failed-curl-56-openssl-ssl-read-ssl-error-syscall-errno)][[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952683/git-push-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200-fatal-the-remote-end-hun)] - the issue seems to be related to the network being slow/unstable (note that I tried increasing git buffer size but that didn't help). It seems to be a local network issue, which I confirmed by going to a different network and being able to do a successful `git clone`.

I'd like to resolve this. My confusion: I'm pretty sure my internet speed is fine: I'm able to get 100 Mbps according to Google's M-Lab internet speed test. If it's simply a question of increasing my internet speed, I can pay more and get on a better plan with my current ISP, but I want to confirm that the issue is actually because of speed (I'm not sure why it would be - why would `git clone` or rather `curl` give up because of slow speed? I'm happy for it to take a long time as long as it does complete). If it's not a question of speed, but rather stability, what would be a good way to diagnose this so I can take that info to my ISP? I called up my ISP and they have no clue why a long-running `curl` command would be failing. I'm able to download the zip from https://github.com/chromium/chromium/releases without it failing.

Comment: a quick-fix would be to add `--depth 1`, btw i think this question fits better on superuser.com

Comment: 54 = "connection reset by peer" = they dropped their TCP stream to you. This is indeed a network issue, but it's not necessarily at your end, nor in the middle: it could be at *their* end. These are difficult to diagnose; packet traces from both ends are very helpful, but that requires that you have someone at the other end who can make one. 

Comment: @torek by "they" you mean github.com? or ISP?

Comment: Whoever is at the other end of your connection. If you're going through a proxy, the proxy is "them"; if not, github.com is "them".